Spring boot embedded Tomcat; how to set CertificateKeystoreFile
We are using Spring Boot 3.2.3 with embedded Tomcat 10.1.19.
We set SSL Bundle configuration
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.ssl.jks
server.ssl.bundle=web-server
spring.ssl.bundle.jks.web-server.key.alias=ourAlias
spring.ssl.bundle.jks.web-server.key.password=thepassword
spring.ssl.bundle.jks.web-server.keystore.location=the/path/to/jks/file
spring.ssl.bundle.jks.web-server.keystore.password=thepassword

In org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.SslConnectorCustomizer#applySslBundle
private void applySslBundle(SslBundle sslBundle, AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol<?> protocol, SSLHostConfig sslHostConfig) {
...
    certificate.setCertificateKeystorePassword(keystorePassword);
    if (key.getPassword() != null) {
        certificate.setCertificateKeyPassword(key.getPassword());
    }

    if (key.getAlias() != null) {
        certificate.setCertificateKeyAlias(key.getAlias());
    }
...
}

We see calls to
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate#setCertificateKeyAlias
and
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate#setCertificateKeyPassword
but we don't see any call to org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate#setCertificateKeystoreFile
How do we set a value to
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate#certificateKeystoreFile?
